# Remap Ctrl+PageUp, Ctrl+PageDown (switch tabs in gnome)

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, xdotool

In gnome-shell, if you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>, you can switch to the previous tab.  However, when I'm on a laptop, there are no <kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>Page Up</kbd> keys.  So, I would like to map this key combination to something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>.

I have tried doing this in the *System Settings* of gnome-shell, under the *Custom shortcuts*.  I set the command to be run as `xdotool key Ctrl+Prior` and `xdotool key Ctrl+Next`.  If I run this command at a terminal prompt, this switches the tabs as expected. However, doing it as a keyboard shortcut, it appears it never runs `xdotool`.

I have also tried doing this with `xbindkeys`, but it just seems like it's not running `xdotool`.

Is there a better way to map these keys in gnome-shell?

Answer (score 4):

The code for keybinding starts from line 558 (may be different in your system),
in file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/viewSelector.js`.

I rebound it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>s</kbd> (and I am wondering how to bind it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>Tab</kbd>)

```
    } else if (modifiers & Clutter.ModifierType.CONTROL_MASK) {
        if (symbol == Clutter.s) {
            if (!this._searchTab.active)
                this._prevTab();
            return true;
        } else if (symbol == Clutter.Tab) {
            if (!this._searchTab.active)
                this._nextTab();
            return true;
        }
```